# Node.js connections with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need help with creating my server because it won't work. I am trying to connect my server with MongoDB using Mongoose and Express.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/node');
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/node';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB);

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

//check DB erorr
db.on('erorr',function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

app.listen('2701`enter code here`7',function(){
    console.log('server localhost is 27017....')
});

Comment: Have you started your `mongod` server? Check connection like this: `db.on('connected', function () {console.log("db connected");})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global.express = require('express');
global.app = express();
global.mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/node";
mongoose.connect(dbURI);

// CONNECTION EVENTS
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
    console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + dbURI);
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Mongoose connection error: ' + err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function() {
    console.log('Mongoose disconnected');
});

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.send('Hello World');
})

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('server is running on port 3000')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you start MongoDB server? To start MongoDb run mongod.exe. 
Go to command promt and type "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe". 
For more details: https://docs.mongodb.com/tutorials/install-mongodb-on-windows/